# Set GLSLValidatorPath in VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, glsl

I start to reading [The book of shader](https://thebookofshaders.com/) and I want to develop something in VsCode.

I installed these extensions:

- GLSL lint
- glsl-canvas
- Shaderc GLSL Linter
- Shader languages support for VS Code
- glsl-literal

When I save a `*.frag` file I get:

```
GLSL Lint: config.glslangValidatorPath is empty, please set it to the executable
```

and

```
Shaderc Lint: config.glslcPath is empty, please set it to the executable
```

I read I have to set the GLSLValidator path using [glslang](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang) but I don't understand how.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 13):

The VSCode plugin **GLSL lint** doesn't come with a shader file validator so you have to download it yourself and setup the path in VSCode.

You can get a built binary [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang/releases/tag/master-tot) for your system. Just download and extract it somewhere on your system and set the path in VSCode settings:

- On Windows/Linux - File > Preferences > Settings
- On macOS - Code > Preferences > Settings

And add the line
 `config.glslangValidatorPath: /your/path/to/glslangbinary` to it.

Hopes it helps.

Best,
Philippe

Comment: I do that: `"config.glslangValidatorPath": "../../../glslang-master-osx-Release/bin/glslangValidator"` but I get `Unknown configuration setting`

Comment: Sorry maybe try **glsllint.glslangValidatorPath": "/your/path/to/glslangbinary"**. This is for the settings.json. If you use the GUI just find the line "Glslang Validator Path".

Comment: What is supposed to happen afterwards? I get no linting, and vscode is complaining about no formatter being installed for `glsl` files.

Comment: I have the exact same issue using WSL on VSCode for Windows. Did you have any luck setting up the validator path correctly or should I just open a new question?

Comment: I posted an answer for WSL below

Answer (score 6):

Press Ctrl+P, type 'settings.json' and enter, and then add

`"glsllint.glslangValidatorPath": "C:\\Path\\Goes\\Here\\glslangValidator.exe"`

and save.

This worked for me (using Windows 10 x64 and VS Code 1.52.1).

Answer (score 2):

What works for me was:

1. File > Preferences > settings
2. Go to Extensions > GLSL linter config
3. Edit in settings.json

   ```
    {
        "glsl-linter.validatorPath": "C:/glslang/bin/glslangValidator",
        "glsl-linter.fileExtensions": 
        {         
            ".fs.glsl": "frag",
            ".vs.glsl": "vert",
            ".tes.glsl": "tese",
            ".tcs.glsl": "tesc",
            ".gs.glsl": "geom"
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSCode with WSL, check my answer on this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66189115/7841421