# What is the correct way to set the Glsland Validator Path on the GLSL Lint extension for VSCode on Windows (using WSL)

Tags: visual-studio-code, glsl

Trying to play around with shaders on the browser and just installed the [GLSL Lint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CADENAS.vscode-glsllint) for VSCode, which apparently needs to know the path to a `glslangValidator` binary before working properly.

Said binary can (I'm assuming) be found here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang/releases/tag/master-tot

However, I've already tried multiple combinations of installation paths, both within Linux and Windows, to no avail: the extension keeps spewing an `ENOENT` error as can be seen in the picture below:

[image]

Considering my setup (Using VS Code on Windows with WSL), where exactly should I place this binary file so that GLSL Lint can properly find it?

I tried, for example, both `~/glslang/bin/glslangValidator` and `C:\\Users\\{User}\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\TheDebianProject.DebianGNULinux_31v5hhsz12ds6\\LocalState\\rootfs\\home\\glslang\\bin\\glslangValidator` (among other installation paths), but so far none worked.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem, did you ever get this to work?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, check my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just figured it out--the problem is that using VSCode with WSL will change the file system that the path should be written in. Instead of downloading the windows binary `glslangValidator.exe`, you should download the linux binary `glslangValidator`. [Check this link and copy the url of the latest release](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang/releases/tag/master-tot), then download it like so:

```sh
cd ~ # Or wherever you want it
wget https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang/releases/download/master-tot/glslang-master-linux-Release.zip
unzip glslang-master-linux-Release.zip -d glslang
```

Then, you need to set the `glslangValidatorPath` to the WSL path:

```
"glsllint.glslangValidatorPath": "/home/<username>/glslang/bin/glslangValidator"
```

*Of course, replace `<username>` with your username, and if you installed it in a different directory, use that path instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Windows and installed `glslang` in my root path. After that I set the path parameter like this and it worked:

`"glsllint.glslangValidatorPath": "C:/glslang/bin/glslangValidator.exe"`

Alternatively, you could add `C:/glslang/bin` to your `PATH` variable.

Comment: I tried that and still get the same error: `GLSL Lint: Failed to spawn 'glslangValidator' binary. Error: spawn C:/glslang/bin/glslangValidator.exe ENOENT`. The file _is_ there, mind you (you're just gonna have to trust me on this one).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows
The following helped me: change the extension of the vertex shader file to ".vert" and the extension of the fragment shader file to ".frag".

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue, but am *not* using WSL like the accepted answer.

What worked for me was actually really dumb: the GLSL Lint error is that it failed to *spawn* the process, not just failed to find. If you download the file from the link in the OP and update `glsllint.glslangValidatorPath` in Settings, GLSL Lint will find the file, but still fail to execute it... because Windows Defender is blocking the exe you downloaded.

Simply running the exe manually via double-click and choosing "Run anyway" whitelisted the program, allowing GLSL Lint to run it. You need to restart VSCode after this, and then it will no longer be an issue.